# Is it possible to force windows update to only download from computers on the local network?

Tags: windows-10, windows-update

Windows 10 update has the ability to download updates from other computers on the same network. This is very helpful to me as I am on a limited and expensive wireless connection. The problem I've encountered is that Windows doesn't always download from machines on the same network, even if those machines have already downloaded the update in question. I've have seen my machines share updates previously, but it isn't consistent.

Is there a way to configure (or hack) windows update so that it will download updates ONLY from computers on the local network and not from the internet? If this was possible, I would configure one machine to download the updates from the internet and the rest to only download from the local network.

I've Googled around but turned up empty.

Answer (score 3):

There is the [Microsoft Windows Server Update Services](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/windowsserver/bb332157.aspx)  which is meant for IT Administrators, but should help you with your problem.

Essentially, you create your own update server from which your network computers download updates, while your server clones the windows update repository.

This probably is the most "formal" version, however you need to configure all computers for the new update server, and have to setup this server beforehand. The advantage here is that after these steps the process runs automatically as before.

**Alternative:**

And easy alternative would be to use a tool such as [WSUS Offline Update](http://www.wsusoffline.net/), which downloads the update files and lets you execute them manually. Here you only would have to deactivate the automatic updates, download the updates manually once every few weeks on a stick/network drive, and then run them locally on every system.

Other then with the above solution, here you would have to put some effort into having an updated system every now and then, since you completely avoid automation.

Comment: Will WSUS run on Windows 10? Or is a server edition of Windows required? From what I can tell, as server edition is required.

Comment: @Icode4food: That seems [true](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd939928%28v=ws.10%29.aspx#serverswall). Hadn't considered this, but it just adds up to the effort necessary.

Comment: I download WSUS and attempted to install. Windows gave me a generic message saying that this program wasn't compatible with this version of windows and killed the installer immediately after it finished extracting. My feeling is that the problem is more to do with it not being compatible with Windows 10, not the fact that I'm not on a server version of Windows.

Comment: Ah, I'm sorry, I think I got confused. My above comment was about the other tool.
However, WSUS should run in Windows 10, since the Changelog [Download](http://download.wsusoffline.net/) section lists changes for Win10 updates. Then again, [this](http://dellwindowsreinstallationguide.com/wsus-offline-update/) guide names problems with Windows 8, so maybe that continues on to Windows 10. I myself only use Windows 7, so I cannot help you there, sorry - I had simply assumed it would work similarly.